# AverageIFS with multiple IF criteria from the same column

Tags: excel, formula, average, excel-2019

I tried looking for solutions here but sadly enough I can't find a similar enough issue related to mine. I have quite a lengthy AVERAGEIFS formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Hoofdtab!AE2:AE19883;
    Hoofdtab!V2:V19883;"="&'Statistics Query'!F4;
    Hoofdtab!V2:V19883;"="&'Statistics Query'!F5;
    Hoofdtab!V2:V19883;"="&'Statistics Query'!F6;
    Hoofdtab!V2:V19883;"="&'Statistics Query'!F7;
    Hoofdtab!I2:I19883;">="&F8;
    Hoofdtab!I2:I19883;"<="&F9;
    Hoofdtab!X2:X19883;"="&F10)
```

The following screenshot should provide some more clarity:

[image: Formula/sheet overview]

There are a lot of "Product" entries in the reference list. I want to make it so that I can filter on two / three/ four (cell F5 / F6 / F7) products at once. Currently I am using the asterisk as an 'everything counts' sign. In the example I am only using one product and this works. However, once I add a second product in cell F5 I get a #DIV/0! error. Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

I am using Excel 2019

Kind regards,

VHes

Comment: You are getting `DIV/0` because your AVERAGEIFS function requires that ALL criteria be met on each entry.  Since your criteria range cannot be equal to 2 products at the same time, it will fail. Do you have the `SEQUENCE` function?

Comment: I see, that is quite logical actually.

No I do not seem to have the sequence function. What does it do and where do I obtain it (other version of excel I assume or an add-in?)

Thanks for your reply Ron!

Comment: `SEQUENCE` is available in Excel in O365.  Online Excel HELP explains its function better than I can in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you need to return an array from which you can return the relevant values.  `AVERAGEIFS` requires that all the conditions be true. But you seem to want one **OR** any of several conditions to be true, in conjunction with another group of conditions where two of them must always be true.

Here is an example that you can use the principles to apply to your actual problem.

Given the following data:

[image]

Assume

- we want to select any of a list which might contain `a, b, and/or c`
- and we want to include a date range.
- we want to average the relevant values in the `value` column
- we name the

  - column of letters `critRng1`
  - the column of dates `critRng2`
  - the column of values `avgRng`

We have a range where we include our crit values (named `crit1`
We have a range with the beginning date of the range, and the ending date (`DATE1` and `DATE2`)

For this exercise, we will assume that

- **crit1** (*note the empty cell*)

[image]

and our Dates:

[image]

The formula:  `=1/(critRng1=TRANSPOSE(crit1))*1/(critRng2>=DATE1)*1/(critRng2<=DATE2)*avgRng`

will return an array of values

[image]

Note that the desired values that we wish to average are present, along with a bunch of `#DIV/0!` errors.

Since the `AVERAGE` function will ignore text, we can use `IFERROR` and `AVERAGE` to get the answer:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(1/(critRng1=TRANSPOSE(crit1))*1/(critRng2>=DATE1)*1/(critRng2<=DATE2)*avgRng,""))
```

or, a bit shorter:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(1/((critRng1=TRANSPOSE(crit1))*(critRng2>=DATE1)*(critRng2<=DATE2))*avgRng,""))
```

For the above conditions, the formula will return `4`  *(average of `5, 4 and 3`)*

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've fallen extremely ill. I will get back to you once I recover. Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: @VHes Not a problem. Hope you have a speedy and complete recovery.